# Rails I18n 'lazy lookup' adding '.html' to the key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I've got a 'standalone' Rails view file (it isn't wrapped in application.html.erb and contains its own DOCTYPE, head and html tags) but when I use the Rails I18n functions and lazy lookup, I seem to get an extra '.html' added.  So for example if the file is called:

```
map.html.erb
```

and contains the request

```
... t('.title')
```

then Rails tries to find the I18n entry for key

```
'map.html.title'
```

Is this normal?

The i18n-tasks tool doesn't expect the extra '.html' so how can I get both the code to work and also make i18n-tasks happy without completely disabling I18n checking for this file?

Comment: shouldnt it be just `t('title')`

Comment: @Fallenhero: nah, that's a feature of I18n, "search in the current namespace"

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works for me is to make use of the scope: option on the I18n.t() call.  This allows me to set the scope by hand leaving both the code and the I18n UTs happy.

However I suspect that the proper answer will be for me to figure out how to refactor what is essentially a standalone HTML page in a Rails environment into something that is 'Railsy' but without ending up with all the wrapping that goes with my real Rails-generated pages.